# Template10 Validation

Tags: validation, uwp-xaml, template10

There is a great sample included with the Template10 source called "Validation".  I'm trying to replicate that validation in my project, but I find that when I include the Template10 NuGet package, Template10.Validation is not included.

Whereas I can include the "Template10.Validation.dll" that I get from compiling the Template10 source myself, I would think the NuGet package should include it.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!

Brad.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Hi Bradley, take a closer look at the sample. In order to use the Validation assembly, you have to download it from GitHub and use it. Validation is not currently in NuGet, but after about a hundred requests like yours, I am starting to reconsider that decision. In the meanwhile, all the code is on GitHub for you to use, steal, and including in your project with my blessing.

The Star Trek look of the sample is my favorite part! :) #LLAP